# ¿Cómo muestro un heatmap en matplotlib?

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib

Tengo un archivo `csv` que contiene las columnas: "Age,Gender,Education Level,Job Title,Years of Experience,Salary,Country,Race" ; y el siguiente código de `python` en `vscode

```
    import pandas as pd
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import seaborn as sns
    import numpy as np
    from scipy.stats import norm
    from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
    from scipy import stats
    import warnings
    
    
    sal = pd.read_csv("salarios_data.csv")
    cormat = sal.corr()
    f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,9))
    sns.heatmap(cormat, vmax= .8, square = True)
    plt.show()
```

Cuando quiero desplegar el `heatmap` me sale el error

> "ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Male' ".

¿Qué debo de hacer con la tabla antes de poder desplegar el heatmap? tengo entendido que no despliega el heatmap porque algunas columnas de mi tabla tienen valores no numéricos

Comment: "tengo entendido que no despliega el heatmap porque algunas columnas de mi tabla tienen valores no numéricos" es lo que dice el error.. dudo que podamos ayudarte mas... que esperas que hagan por vos?? de paso, vs code es un editor de texto (con esteroides)... ahi, no vas a mostrar nada, y tu problema no tiene nada que ver con eso...

Comment: Hola. Pues eso. Tienes un campo categórico (Male, Female, etc) y necesitas preprocesarlo para poder correr el análisis que estás haciendo.

Answer (score 0):

¡Correcto! Estás en el camino correcto al identificar que el error se debe a que algunas columnas de tu tabla tienen valores no numéricos.

El método corr() de Pandas intenta calcular las correlaciones entre las columnas de tu DataFrame. Dado que solo es posible calcular correlaciones entre valores numéricos, cuando intenta hacerlo con columnas de texto (como 'Gender', 'Education Level', 'Job Title', 'Country', 'Race'), se produce el error que mencionas.

Para solucionar este problema, puedes hacer lo siguiente:

Eliminar columnas no numéricas: Una forma directa de solucionar el problema es simplemente excluir las columnas no numéricas antes de calcular la matriz de correlación.

```
sal_numeric = sal.select_dtypes(include=[np.number])
cormat = sal_numeric.corr()
```

Codificar columnas categóricas: Otra opción es convertir columnas categóricas en numéricas a través de técnicas de codificación como "one-hot encoding" o "label encoding". Sin embargo, ten en cuenta que calcular correlaciones con estas columnas codificadas podría no tener mucho sentido semántico, ya que estas codificaciones no necesariamente representan relaciones numéricas válidas entre categorías.

Si decides seguir esta ruta, puedes usar pd.get_dummies() para el "one-hot encoding" o LabelEncoder de sklearn para el "label encoding".

Aquí hay un ejemplo usando "one-hot encoding":

```
sal_encoded = pd.get_dummies(sal)
cormat = sal_encoded.corr()
```

Después de aplicar una de las soluciones anteriores, puedes seguir con tu código original para trazar el heatmap.